# Syntax error in python script of raspberry pi

Tags: python, syntax, raspberry-pi

I'm new in python and total stranger to python indentation. I get syntax error whenever I try to run the following code, what is the problem with it? Thanks already.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def RC_Analog (Pin):  
 counter = 0  
 # Discharge capacitor  
 GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.OUT)  
 GPIO.output(Pin, GPIO.LOW)  
 time.sleep(0.1)  
 GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.IN)  
 # Count loops until voltage across capacitor reads high on GPIO  
 while(GPIO.input(Pin)==GPIO.LOW):  
  counter =counter+1  
 return counter  

# Set up header pin 11 as an input
triggerPin = 25;
echoPin = 8;
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(triggerPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(echoPin, GPIO.IN)

while True:
 GPIO.output(triggerPin, False)
 time.sleep(0.000002)
 GPIO.output(triggerPin, True)
 time.sleep(0.00001)
 GPIO.output(triggerPin, False)
 print RC_Analog(echoPin)/58
 time.sleep (0.25)
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual error message?

Comment: The SyntaxError will tell you which line the problem is on.

Comment: def?RC_Analog(Pin) it highlights the question marked area

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: whatdo you mean by that? the only information shell gives is "There is a syntax error in your code"

Comment: Always use four space characters for indentation.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't tell you the line number where the error is? How are you running your program?

Comment: If it literally prints `def?RC_Analog(Pin)`, it sounds like you have something other than a space between the `def` and the `RC_Analog`, maybe some weird Unicode character which is similar to a space.

Comment: I checked, and sadly there is not. I replaced indentation spaces with 4 spaces, and now it gives syntax error near import?RPi.GPIO as GPIO. The ? is highlighted

Comment: Please run `python --version`. If you're running python 3, then your print on line 31 should be written `print(RC_Analog(echoPin)/58)`.

Comment: im using python 2.7. I realized the semicolons could be problem, corrected them, but still nothing seems working.

Comment: Aya, turns out you were right. The function I copied didnt fit in the code and bring weird whitespace-like characters which I should correct. Maybe its about my locale, I didnt really get it. But if you post this as an answer, im happy to rate as best answer. My best regards!

Comment: @mozcelikors Added answer with a little more info.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really using python to launch your script ? I can get an error at the same place if I try to source it as a shell script:

`. test.py`

Make sure you launch it with python:

`python test.py`

or make it executable:
`chmod u+x test.py`
and launch it with:
`./test.py`

Comment: your answer is useful, but nothing i didnt already do. thanks anyway. The problem was with the utf-8 whitespace thing, it turned out.

Answer (score 1):

> `def?RC_Analog(Pin)` it highlights the question marked area

If you see the code as `def RC_Analog(Pin)`, but the syntax error message literally prints `def?RC_Analog(Pin)`, it sounds like you have something other than an ASCII space character between the `def` and the `RC_Analog`, like a Unicode [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), or some other Unicode character which is similar to a space.

Replacing it with a space typed from your keyboard should solve the problem.

When writing a Python script, it's best to ensure you only use the 7-bit ASCII character set. Some text editors will let you set this in a configuration option, others will let you choose an encoding when saving.

If you're using Windows Notepad, select type "ANSI" when saving.

Answer (score 0):

If you get

```
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO
```

you need to install the module first

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO

Comment: `ImportError` is different from `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Well in John Brown's defense, you are being pretty vague about exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: I know but as i said, im new to it, so i dont know what information else should i provide, the only information shell gives to me is that there is a syntax error.